# Drunk alcohol in ekaadshi

Tags: vishnu

I consumed 3-4 ml of alcohol mistakenly without knowing today is ekadashi how can I apologise for it so that it doesn't effect me it wasn't even something like 2 drops that even without knowing

Comment: Alcohol does bad to you anyways not just because you drunk on Ekadasi, so dont worry.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to apologize for it. Unless someone explicitly asked you to not do it (like your Guru or your spouse) and you agreed to not do it, in which case if you apologize to them, that is sufficient compensation for having taken it.

These type of activities are not categorical sins. Here is what Manu himself states in ManuSmriti:

[image]

But if you have already convinced yourself that unless you do something now, you cannot have peace of mind, then here is what Vyasa tells Yudhistra in Shanti Parva, Chapter 35 in Mahabharata - I DO NOT RECOMMEND YOU DO IT, since hot water can seriously damage your oesophagus if not Stomach also:

> *surā pānaṃ sakṛt pītvā yo'gnivarṇāṃ pibed dvijaḥ,
> sa pāvayaty athātmānam iha loke paratra ca*

**Meaning:** If a person who has taken alcohol once, drinks hot water purifies himself here and hereafter.

Comment: On this site, one may downvote or upvote an answer. It doesn't mean your answer is isn't right or isn't wrong. Please do not use swear words on this site. Be nice when posting an answer or a comment.

Comment: Freedom to do something doesn't mean doing it is either appropriate or right. My choice words were meant for the downvoter, well deserved considering the answer literally provided what the questioner asked.